# Evaluating impact of density of one point pattern data on column in spatial dataframe

Tags: r, kernel-density

I have a dataset. It has data on two types of electric poles (blue and red). I'm trying to find out if the density and size of blue electric poles have an effect of the size of red electric poles.

My data set looks something like this:

| x | y | type | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | 32.2 | blue | 12 |
| 84.3 | 32.1 | red | 11.1 |
| 84.9 | 31.4 | blue | 12.5 |
| 85.2 | 32.5 | blue | 14 |
| 85.6 | 32.3 | red | 10.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

So I have the x and y coordinates of all poles, the type and the size.
I have separated the file into two for the red and blue pole.I created a PPP out of the blue data and using density.ppp() to get the kernel density estimate of the PPP.
Now I'm confused how to go about applying the density to the red poles data.

What I'm specifically looking for is that around a red pole, what the blue pole density and what is the average size of the blue poles around the red pole (using like a 10m buffer zone). So my red pole data should end up looking like this:

| x | y | type | size | bluePoleDen | avgBluePoleSize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | 32.2 | red | 12 | 0.034 | 10.2 |
| 84.3 | 32.1 | red | 11.1 | 0.0012 | 13.8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Following that, I then intend to run regression on this red dataset

So far, I have done the following:

- separated the data into red and blue poles
- made a PPP out of blue pooles
- used density.ppp to generate kernel density estimate for the blue poles ppp
- using the density.ppp result as a function to generate density estimates at each (x,y) position of red poles. so like:

```
     den = density.ppp(blue)
     f = as.function(den)
     blueDens = f(red$x, red$y)
     red$bluePoleDen = blueDens
```

Now I am stuck here. I've been stuck on what packages are available to go further like this in R.